# How can I integrate Opencv into a Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, face-recognition

I'm trying to put face recogniton code that uses opencv to the left hand side of a tkinter window. By doing this I wish to leave the right hand side of the window free so I can output text. e.g. when a face is detected the program will display "Name: Present" I am new to both Tkinter and OpenCV andI can't seem to find a straight answer online. Any Help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code below:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import xlsxwriter
import os
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from datetime import datetime;
import datetime


#Defines time
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

#Setup for period segment of spreadsheetname
if now.hour<9:
    name = "HomeRoom "
elif now.hour==9 and now.min<=50:
    name = "Period1 "
elif now.hour==10 and now.min<=40:
    name = "Period2 "
elif now.hour==11 and now.min<=50:
    name = "Period3 "
elif now.hour==12 and now.min<=40:
    name = "Period4 "
elif now.hour==14 and now.min<=10:
    name = "Period5 "
elif now.hour<=15:
    name = "Period6 "
else:
    name = "Testing "



# Webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# to break loop
Printed = False

#Defines todays date                               #day/month/year-HourAM/PM
todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I%p"))


#Sets up spreadsheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(name + todays_date +'.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Name')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Attendance')
worksheet.write('A6', 'Jordan Terzian')
worksheet.write('B6', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A5', 'Daniel Pearce')
worksheet.write('B5', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A4', 'Ewan Krall')
worksheet.write('B4', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A3', 'Norman Brosow')
worksheet.write('B3', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A2', 'Mitchell Benson')
worksheet.write('B2', 'Absent')

# classmates

jordan_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("jordan.jpg")
jordan_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(jordan_image)[0]

daniel_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("daniel.jpg")
daniel_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(daniel_image)[0]

ewan_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("ewan.jpg")
ewan_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(ewan_image)[0]

norman_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("norman.jpg")
norman_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(norman_image)[0]

mitch_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("mitch.jpg")
mitch_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(mitch_image)[0]



# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    jordan_face_encoding,
    daniel_face_encoding,
    ewan_face_encoding,
    norman_face_encoding,
    mitch_face_encoding,

]
known_face_names = [
    "Jordan Terzian",
    "Daniel Pearce",
    "Ewan Krall",
    "Norman Brosow",
    "Mitchell Benson",

]



# Initialize variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]


    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face,
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        #Writes to spreadsheet and GUI
        if name == "Jordan Terzian" and not Printed:
            print("Jordan Terzian is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B6', 'Present')
        elif name == "Daniel Pearce" and not Printed:
            print("Daniel Pearce is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B5', 'Present')
        elif name == "Ewan Krall" and not Printed:
            print("Ewan Krall is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B4', 'Present')
        elif name == "Norman Brosow" and not Printed:
            print("Norman Brosow is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B3', 'Present')
        elif name == "Mitchell Benson" and not Printed:
            print("Michell Benson is Present")
            Printed = True
            worskheet.write('B2', 'Present')

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam, Closes webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
workbook.close()
```

Comment: put `tkinter.Label()` or `tkinter.Canvas()` on left side and replace frame on Label/Canvas instead of using `cv2.imshow('Video', frame)` . Because loop `while True` will block `tkinter.mainloop()` and freeze tkinter so you have to use `tkinter.after(milliseconds, function)` to run this code periodicaly.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple example which gets `frame` from `cv2` and replaces it in `PhotoImage` which is displayed on `Canvas`. It uses `after()` to run function `update_frame()` periodically so it doesn't block `root.mainloop()` which has to run all time.

You will have to run code from `while True` in function `update_frame()` without using  `while True`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def update_frame():

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    image = Image.fromarray(frame)
    photo.paste(image)

    #description['text'] = 'new text'

    root.after(10, update_frame) # update it again after 10ms

# --- main ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# get first frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# - GUI -

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.fromarray(frame)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)  # it has to be after `tk.Tk()`

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

canvas.create_image((0,0), image=photo, anchor='nw')

description = tk.Label(root, text="Place for description")
description.pack(side='right')

# - start -

update_frame() # update it first time

root.mainloop() # start program - this loop runs all time

# - after close -

cap.release()
```

---

**BTW:** I have example with buttons `Play`, `Stop`, `Save Image`: [python-examples/cv2/tkinter-CV](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20with%20buttons%20to%20start%20and%20stop/main.py)

---

**EDIT:** I can test it but it could be something like this.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter
#from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
#import PySimpleGUI as sg #
import xlsxwriter
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#from datetime import datetime;
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def process_frame():
    global process_this_frame

    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face,
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
        #Writes to spreadsheet and GUI
        if name == "Jordan Terzian" and not Printed:
            print("Jordan Terzian is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B6', 'Present')
        elif name == "Daniel Pearce" and not Printed:
            print("Daniel Pearce is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B5', 'Present')
        elif name == "Ewan Krall" and not Printed:
            print("Ewan Krall is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B4', 'Present')
        elif name == "Norman Brosow" and not Printed:
            print("Norman Brosow is Present")
            Printed = True
            worksheet.write('B3', 'Present')
        elif name == "Mitchell Benson" and not Printed:
            print("Michell Benson is Present")
            Printed = True
            worskheet.write('B2', 'Present')

        description['text'] = name

    image = Image.fromarray(frame)
    photo.paste(image)

    root.after(40, process_frame) # update it again after 40ms - it gives 25 FPS (1000ms/40ms=25)

# --- init ---

#Defines time
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

#Setup for period segment of spreadsheetname
if now.hour<9:
    name = "HomeRoom "
elif now.hour==9 and now.min<=50:
    name = "Period1 "
elif now.hour==10 and now.min<=40:
    name = "Period2 "
elif now.hour==11 and now.min<=50:
    name = "Period3 "
elif now.hour==12 and now.min<=40:
    name = "Period4 "
elif now.hour==14 and now.min<=10:
    name = "Period5 "
elif now.hour<=15:
    name = "Period6 "
else:
    name = "Testing "

# to break loop
Printed = False

#Defines todays date                               #day/month/year-HourAM/PM
todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I%p"))


#Sets up spreadsheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(name + todays_date +'.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Name')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Attendance')
worksheet.write('A6', 'Jordan Terzian')
worksheet.write('B6', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A5', 'Daniel Pearce')
worksheet.write('B5', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A4', 'Ewan Krall')
worksheet.write('B4', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A3', 'Norman Brosow')
worksheet.write('B3', 'Absent')
worksheet.write('A2', 'Mitchell Benson')
worksheet.write('B2', 'Absent')

# classmates

#jordan_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("jordan.jpg")
#jordan_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(jordan_image)[0]
#
#daniel_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("daniel.jpg")
#daniel_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(daniel_image)[0]
#
#ewan_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("ewan.jpg")
#ewan_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(ewan_image)[0]
#
#norman_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("norman.jpg")
#norman_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(norman_image)[0]
#
#mitch_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("mitch.jpg")
#mitch_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(mitch_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
#known_face_encodings = [
#    jordan_face_encoding,
#    daniel_face_encoding,
#    ewan_face_encoding,
#    norman_face_encoding,
#    mitch_face_encoding,
#]

filenames = [
    "jordan.jpg",
    "daniel.jpg",
    "ewan.jpg",
    "norman.jpg",
    "mitch.jpg"
]

known_face_encodings = []

for name in filenames:
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(name)
    face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(face_encoding)

known_face_names = [
    "Jordan Terzian",
    "Daniel Pearce",
    "Ewan Krall",
    "Norman Brosow",
    "Mitchell Benson",
]

# Initialize variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

# --- main ---

# Webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# get first frame to get size
ret, frame = cap.read()

# - GUI -

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.fromarray(frame)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)  # it has to be after `tk.Tk()`

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

canvas.create_image((0,0), image=photo, anchor='nw')

description = tk.Label(root, text="Place for description")
description.pack(side='right')

# - start -

process_frame() # update it first time

root.mainloop() # start program - this loop runs all time

# --- end ---

# Release handle to the webcam, Closes webcam
video_capture.release()
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
workbook.close()
```

Comment: sorry sir but I'm pre much a python beginner and crafted my code using online tutorials, hence I'm not too sure how to implement this. If you had any spare time could you please show me using my code. If not I understand, thanks for your help thus far, I'll keep trying

Comment: I put some code but I didn't test it - so it can have some mistakes. Using time in `after(milliseconds,...)` you can control how often it process image - so you can use it instead of `process_this_frame`